# Adding round corners to Highcharts Bar Chart with stacked bars when value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and I love them, but my issue is that when I add use the round corner plugin, if I have a stacked chart with a 0 in it, then the radius wont be applied.

**Issue:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/akpLx5md/3/) Take a look at Jun and July.

**Goal:** In this case I need a way to assign the radius to the left of june and the right of july.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            animation: false
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 0, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            // usage:
            borderRadiusTopLeft: 5,
            borderRadiusTopRight: 5
        }, {
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            // usage:
            borderRadiusBottomRight: 10,
            borderRadiusBottomLeft: 10
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust `rounded-corners.js` to your needs to something like this

```
(function (H) {
    var curPercentage=[];
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.column.prototype, 'translate', function (proceed) {

        var options = this.options,
            rTopLeft = options.borderRadiusTopLeft || 0,
            rTopRight = options.borderRadiusTopRight || 0,
            rBottomRight = options.borderRadiusBottomRight || 0,
            rBottomLeft = options.borderRadiusBottomLeft || 0,
            topMargin = options.topMargin || 0,
            bottomMargin = options.bottomMargin || 0;

        proceed.call(this);

        if (rTopLeft || rTopRight || rBottomRight || rBottomLeft) {

            H.each(this.points, function (point) {
                var iBottomRight = rBottomRight,
                    iBottomLeft = rBottomLeft,
                    iTopRight = rTopRight,
                    iTopLeft = rTopLeft;

                //console.log(point);
                if (typeof(curPercentage[point.index])=='undefined'){
                    curPercentage[point.index]=0;
                }
                var prevPercentage = curPercentage[point.index];
                curPercentage[point.index]+=1.0*parseFloat(point.percentage).toFixed(6);
                //console.log(prevPercentage);
                //console.log(curPercentage);

                if (prevPercentage==0 & curPercentage[point.index] == 100) {
                    // special case, only one value > 0, preserve all border radius
                    // reset for the next call
                    curPercentage[point.index]=0;

                } else if (prevPercentage==0) {
                    //right side
                    iBottomRight = 0;
                    iBottomLeft = 0;
                } else if (curPercentage[point.index] == 100) {
                    //left side
                    iTopRight = 0;
                    iTopLeft = 0;
                    // reset for the next call
                    curPercentage[point.index]=0;
                } else {
                    // no radius
                    iBottomRight = 0;
                    iBottomLeft = 0;
                    iTopRight = 0;
                    iTopLeft = 0;
                }

                var shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs,
                    w = shapeArgs.width,
                    h = shapeArgs.height,
                    x = shapeArgs.x,
                    y = shapeArgs.y;

                // Preserve the box for data labels
                point.dlBox = point.shapeArgs;

                point.shapeType = 'path';
                point.shapeArgs = {
                    d: [
                        'M', x + iTopLeft, y + topMargin,
                    // top side
                    'L', x + w - iTopRight, y + topMargin,
                    // top right corner
                    'C', x + w - iTopRight / 2, y, x + w, y + iTopRight / 2, x + w, y + iTopRight,
                    // right side
                    'L', x + w, y + h - iBottomRight,
                    // bottom right corner
                    'C', x + w, y + h - iBottomRight / 2, x + w - iBottomRight / 2, y + h, x + w - iBottomRight, y + h + bottomMargin,
                    // bottom side
                    'L', x + iBottomLeft, y + h + bottomMargin,
                    // bottom left corner
                    'C', x + iBottomLeft / 2, y + h, x, y + h - iBottomLeft / 2, x, y + h - iBottomLeft,
                    // left side
                    'L', x, y + iTopLeft,
                    // top left corner
                    'C', x, y + iTopLeft / 2, x + iTopLeft / 2, y, x + iTopLeft, y,
                        'Z']
                };

            });
        }

    });
}(Highcharts));
```

[Working JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w6p50gqn/)

with this change, you will need to set the border radius in all series

```
series: [{
        data: [50, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 0, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        // usage:
        borderRadiusTopLeft: 5,
        borderRadiusTopRight: 5,
        borderRadiusBottomRight: 5,
        borderRadiusBottomLeft: 5,        
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        borderRadiusBottomRight: 10,
        borderRadiusBottomLeft: 10,
        borderRadiusTopLeft: 10,
        borderRadiusTopRight: 10
    }]
```

Comment: Great thanks for the direction, that's way above my JavaScript skills, I am having an issue when I add the third series. http://jsfiddle.net/akpLx5md/5/ Take a look at march, April and November. Do you happen to know why its not working on there?

Comment: This is so close to being the answer, but there is some kind of bug. See my comment above for bug demo

Comment: I fixed the issue, but still a bug. I really appreciate any help you can offer. you already really helped a lot. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wee34nrk/1/

Comment: I was working on a new approach, I think it works alot better. http://jsfiddle.net/wee34nrk/2/

Comment: Freaking genius! I'll try it in a sec and mark as answer. I should pay you.

Comment: thank you so much. The only bug I found is that its failing on the third level of a triple drilldown bar chart. Maybe i'll ask another question for that one.

Comment: :) hope I can help you in the other question, just send me the link

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887665/highcharts-triple-drilldown-round-corners-plugin-bug

Comment: I had a tiny issue with this great extension being sometimes my total is not 100 but 99.99999. The hack I found was to change the `prevPercentage === 100` and `prevPercentage === 0` to another comparison such as `prevPercentage > 99.9` and `prevPercentage < 0.1` (you can adjust those numbers according to your needs).