# Highcharts Triple Drilldown Round Corners Plugin Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using a modified version of the Highcharts Round Corners Plugin thanks to @davcs86. And on the third level of a drilldown there is a bug. I was hoping someone could assist.

**Issue:** the third level in drill down errors out.

**Goal:** Make it work.

**Bug Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/32a7L41b/ Click on Alaska and then Wave 1 and you will see the bug. Obviously the data is not real.

```
//Modified Highcharts Round Corners plugin
  (function (H) {
        var curPercentage = [];
        H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.column.prototype, 'translate', function (proceed) {

            var options = this.options,
                rTopLeft = options.borderRadiusTopLeft || 0,
                rTopRight = options.borderRadiusTopRight || 0,
                rBottomRight = options.borderRadiusBottomRight || 0,
                rBottomLeft = options.borderRadiusBottomLeft || 0,
                topMargin = options.topMargin || 0,
                bottomMargin = options.bottomMargin || 0;

            proceed.call(this);

            if (rTopLeft || rTopRight || rBottomRight || rBottomLeft) {

                H.each(this.points, function (point) {
                    var iBottomRight = rBottomRight,
                        iBottomLeft = rBottomLeft,
                        iTopRight = rTopRight,
                        iTopLeft = rTopLeft;

                    //console.log(point);
                    if (typeof (curPercentage[point.index]) == 'undefined') {
                        curPercentage[point.index] = 0;
                    }
                    var prevPercentage = curPercentage[point.index];
                    curPercentage[point.index] += 1.0 * parseFloat(point.percentage).toFixed(6);
                    //console.log(prevPercentage);
                    //console.log(curPercentage);

                    if (prevPercentage == 0 & curPercentage[point.index] == 100) {
                        // special case, only one value > 0, preserve all border radius
                        // reset for the next call
                        curPercentage[point.index] = 0;

                    } else if (prevPercentage == 0) {
                        //right side
                        iBottomRight = 0;
                        iBottomLeft = 0;
                    } else if (curPercentage[point.index] == 100) {
                        //left side
                        iTopRight = 0;
                        iTopLeft = 0;
                        // reset for the next call
                        curPercentage[point.index] = 0;
                    } else {
                        // no radius
                        iBottomRight = 0;
                        iBottomLeft = 0;
                        iTopRight = 0;
                        iTopLeft = 0;
                    }

                    var shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs,
                        w = shapeArgs.width,
                        h = shapeArgs.height,
                        x = shapeArgs.x,
                        y = shapeArgs.y;

                    // Preserve the box for data labels
                    point.dlBox = point.shapeArgs;

                    point.shapeType = 'path';
                    point.shapeArgs = {
                        d: [
                            'M', x + iTopLeft, y + topMargin,
                        // top side
                        'L', x + w - iTopRight, y + topMargin,
                        // top right corner
                        'C', x + w - iTopRight / 2, y, x + w, y + iTopRight / 2, x + w, y + iTopRight,
                        // right side
                        'L', x + w, y + h - iBottomRight,
                        // bottom right corner
                        'C', x + w, y + h - iBottomRight / 2, x + w - iBottomRight / 2, y + h, x + w - iBottomRight, y + h + bottomMargin,
                        // bottom side
                        'L', x + iBottomLeft, y + h + bottomMargin,
                        // bottom left corner
                        'C', x + iBottomLeft / 2, y + h, x, y + h - iBottomLeft / 2, x, y + h - iBottomLeft,
                        // left side
                        'L', x, y + iTopLeft,
                        // top left corner
                        'C', x, y + iTopLeft / 2, x + iTopLeft / 2, y, x + iTopLeft, y,
                            'Z']
                    };

                });
            }

        });
    }(Highcharts));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I had to modify `drilldown.js` to support the data saved in `point.dlBox`

```
Chart.prototype.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown = function (point, ddOptions) {
    /// (...)
    // Add a record of properties for each drilldown level
    level = {
        levelNumber: levelNumber,
        seriesOptions: oldSeries.options,
        levelSeriesOptions: levelSeriesOptions,
        levelSeries: levelSeries,
        shapeArgs: point.dlBox || point.shapeArgs, // <== here
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/32a7L41b/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Your example works great. But for some reason on my page, on the second level of the drilldown the first bar will be round, the second will be square the next three will be round and then all the rest are square. And this happens on all the levels of the drill down after I initially drilldown. I cant recreate it in your demo though. you get the answer because this solved the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
drilldown: {
    series: [{
    borderRadius: 7, // <----------
    id: 'alaskawaves',
    name: 'Alaska Waves',
```

I got it worked by adding **borderRadius: 7** inside series object. If you see any drilled down bar as square, just add this borderRadius inside related series object.

Here is example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ht1u0og2/